# Apache Camel - sending a Properties object over the route

Tags: java, message-queue, apache-camel

I have a Properties object that contains all the fields to be sent as a message to consumer's queue.

What is the recommended way to pass Properties-like objects? Shall I set a header for every key in Properties object or can I just attach the Properties object to the message body (if the former, how is it done?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Properties or Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330998/passing-values-between-processors-in-apache-camel/10342011) to pass objects. If you pass the entire Properties objects inside a specific Camel property (As it can carry java objects) or if you actually put each property as a new Camel property is pretty much a matter of taste from your side.

Or as you say, pass it in the message body, although you might want other things there. Think of all those fields as a toolbox. Use it in the most convenient way.